# How to add $user_paid_period (int) to $paid_end(datetime) within $_POST()

Tags: php, wordpress

For a subscription I have to add a year period ($user_paid_period) to $paid_end(datetime) within $_POST().

I have tried a lot but can not fix it. Here below my code. 
It generates a blanc screen.

Someone of you who can help me?

```
    if(isset($_POST['user_paid_period']) ) {
        $user_paid_end = $_POST['user_paid_period'];
        update_user_meta($customer->ID, 'paid_period', $user_paid_end);

        $paid_end = new DateTime($user_paid_end);
        $paid_end = $paid_end->add(new DateInterval('P2YMDHMS'));
        $paid_end = $paid_end->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        update_user_meta($customer->ID, 'paid_end', $paid_end); 
   }
```

Comment: blank screen can mean syntax errors. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: I get no errors.
@ini_set('display_errors', 1);
@ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: update_user_meta() stays empty after $_POST()

Answer (score 4):

If you want to set paid end date according to $_POST, you can do the following:

```
if(isset($_POST['user_paid_period']) ) {
       $user_paid_start = strtotime($_POST['user_paid_date']);
       $user_paid_end = strtotime('+ ' . $_POST['user_paid_period'] . ' years', $user_paid_start);

       $paid_end = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $user_paid_end);
       echo 'User has paid until ' . $paid_end;

       update_user_meta($customer->ID, 'paid_end', $paid_end); 
}
```

(see http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

If you wanted to extend an existing subscription, you can do the following (assuming you are using Wordpress):

```
if(isset($_POST['user_paid_period']) ) {
       $paid_end_current = get_user_meta($customer->ID, 'paid_end', TRUE);
       $user_paid_start = strtotime($paid_end_current);
       $user_paid_end = strtotime('+ ' . $_POST['user_paid_period'] . ' years', $user_paid_start);

       $paid_end = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $user_paid_end);
       echo 'User has paid until ' . $paid_end;

       update_user_meta($customer->ID, 'paid_end', $paid_end); 
}
```

Comment: Raphael thanks. But I must check. Have problem with 
$_POST['user_paid_date']; result = 23/04/2014
date format is not correct as you see.

Comment: The format of $_POST['user_paid_date'] shouldn't matter, since strtotime() can take almost every format and converts it to unix timestamp. In the end you get something like "2024-04-23 00:00:00" because of the following: date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $user_paid_end);

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add 1 year, so you should change 'P2YMDHMS' to simply 'P1Y' (='P'eriod of '1' 'Y'ear).

Comment: No not 1 year only for this example. THe periods are mutliple.
if I echo as below, result is empty:

Comment: Then enter the exact period. For example, 1 year and 2 months? P1Y2M. You've entered 'MD...' without any value and that's a no-no.

Comment: empty result:
$paid_end = new DateTime($user_paid_end);
   echo $paid_end->date; die();

Comment: empty result:
$paid_end = new DateTime($user_paid_end);
   echo $paid_end->date; die();
if I echo $_POST['user_paid_date']; result = 23/04/2014
echo $_POST['user_paid_period']; result = 10
means: $paid_end = 23/04/2024

Comment: Is it possible you've written $user_paid_end = $_POST['user_paid_period']; when you actually wanted $user_paid_end = $_POST['user_paid_date']; ?

Comment: just check. see no errors:
  if(isset($_POST['user_paid_period']) ) {
   $user_paid_period = $_POST['user_paid_period'];
   update_user_meta($customer->ID, 'paid_period', $user_paid_period);

   $paid_date = new DateTime($user_paid_date);
   $paid_end = $paid_date->add(new DateInterval('P2YMDHMS'));
   $paid_end = $paid_end->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   
   update_user_meta($customer->ID, 'paid_end', $paid_end);  
  }

Comment: I have found the solution. I forgot to redraw the dates. 
Here the result that operates fine. Thanks everyone for your patience and cooperation!!!
  if(isset($_POST['user_paid_period']) ) {
      $user_paid_start = strtotime($_POST['user_paid_date']);
      $user_paid_end = strtotime('+ ' . $_POST['user_paid_period'] . ' years', $user_paid_start);
  
      $paid_end = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $user_paid_end);
      echo 'User has paid until ' . $paid_end;
  
      update_user_meta($customer->ID, 'paid_end', $paid_end); 
  }